Show all info windows on a oracle map on the same time
i have map like this map
is there a way to view all info windows the same time for all map makers?
I am sure its can be done with a dynamic action on resource load, but i cannot find the javascript o load the info window.
i dont now but there is a showOnlyActiveInfoWindow and it can be set to false,it meens all info windows can be displayed, but how can i use he in a dynamic acion
the idea is when a point is clicket all infowindows are showing, not only the one from the current marker
This is a oracle map plugin, with maptiler integration.
Oracle Apex23.2
